# How to display image laravel

Tags: laravel, image

My store \public\uploads

views

```
 <img src="{{asset('public/uploads/'.$members->image)}}" id="display-image" style="width:80%">
```

What wrong ?

Comment: is it `storage`  `public` or laravel `public` folder ?

Comment: `public` should not be in the path unless you have a `public` folder in your `public` folder, since `public` should be the docroot/webroot

Comment: So where should I keep?

Comment: Kamlesh. it public floder

Comment: Would be `{{ asset('/uploads/'.$members->image) }}`

Comment: It doesn't show

Comment: you need to check what url is being generated and that url is correct

Comment: Whats about with this `src="/uploads/{{ $members->image }}"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove public from src url..

```
 <img src="{{asset('uploads/'.$members->image)}}" id="display-image" style="width:80%">
```

helper asset by default point towards public folder, if you pass public to src url
,will look for another public folder under public folder which is not exists, thats why it gives you error.

[for more details on asset helper, vist the link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset)

hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

First, to show images in tags img need make a link of folder storage, your images needs be in storage folder. See doc https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#introduction
After this step you can show with `echo asset('storage/file.jpg');`